# Using javascript to go to the next tabindex of a form AFTER a refresh

Tags: javascript, forms, tabindex

I am currently working on an already established system that I cant make very drastic changes to. I need to "autosave" a form every time one of the fields is entered/updated. To do this I bound an event to the onblur of every field

```
document.form.submit();
```

It goes to the processing page, does what needs to be done and comes back to the form and retrieves the information from mysql to display it. It does have a bit of a "flash" from the reload but this is not a problem. The real problem is the user loses their tabindex since essentially the page is reloaded. So when tab is pressed the form is submitted and reloaded and the tab starts back from the beginning instead of the next field as the user would expect it to.

Is there a solution using javascript (no jquery) that I could implement that would "remember" the field the user was in and go to the next field after the form is submitted?

thank you!!

Comment: just to absolutly clarify here, you are talking about cursor position, right? my first thought is to write something into the url that saves your tab index, but that might take some figuring out/ might not work

Comment: what would the difference between cursor position and tabindex be? I also thought I could use a hidden field to send over the tabindex, retrieve it again add 1 to it and tell the form to focus there

Comment: i was just making sure he didn't have navigation style tabs (i like to be clear, but i guess i wasn't) I also thought about sending tab index back and forth, but it feels dirty, since it is very much a client side piece of data. of course, depending on how complicated/ mature/ how many different interfaces you want/ may want to your web application sending the tab index back and forth might be the best solution.

Comment: It is very much a basic form, mostly input type=text but a few dropdowns and textarea. Normally tabbing even without a tabindex is perfectly  natural. Just as I said, on a refresh the tab (obviously) starts back at the beginning.

Comment: i've never done ajax with bare js (always used jquery) but i like the idea of that. I thought I saw that suggested earlier

Comment: I saw it also but it seemed to disappear directly after. Possibly they realized I said I couldnt make major changes and deleted.

Comment: it might not take major changes to pull off ajax, the tricky part might be ajaxing w/o jquery. As I said, never done it.

Comment: @hhamilton I asked another question and got a comment stating to use onunload event to save the form whenever the person navigates away from the page. Seems to do the job I need, to save the form without hitting a "submit" button. I thank you for your interest in my question!